# Can all wildcards in Java be replaced by non-wildcard types?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I can't find any example where wildcards can't be replaced by a generic.
For example:

```
 public void dummy(List<? extends MyObject> list);
```

is equivalent to

```
 public <T> void dummy(List<T extends MyObject> list);
```

or

```
 public <T> List<? extends T> dummy2(List<? extends T> list);
```

is equivalent to

```
 public <T, U>  List<U extends T> dummy(List<U extends T> list);
```

So I don't undertand why wildcard was created as generics is already doing the job. Any ideas or comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, it is not always replaceable.

```
List<? extends Reader> foo();
```

is not equivalent to

```
<T> List<T extends Reader> foo();
```

because you don't know the `T` when calling `foo()` (and you cannot know what `List<T>` will `foo()` return. The same thing happens in your second example, too.

The [demonstration of using wildcards can be found in this (my) answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103710/what-has-been-learned-about-making-variance-part-of-the-type/106026#106026).

Comment: I forgot that ! Anyway, my remark concerning [Angelika Lanker's FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Resources/Links/JavaGenerics.htm) stays true :-)

Comment: from caller's point of view, `foo1()` can only be assigned to `List<? extends Reader> x = foo1()`. such usages can be replaced by `List<? extends Reader> x = foo2()`. therefore `foo1` can be replaced by `foo2` (reverse isn't true). in the method body, foo2 can't really take advantage of `T`, so foo1 and foo2 impl are basically the same.

Comment: @irreputable: The first point is true, foo2 can be used in place of foo1. However, their implementation possibilities are substantially different, because foo1 can choose the type of list element. An example worth more than a thousand words: http://ideone.com/YKLum

Answer (score 2):

An easy answer is that, deeper level wildcards can't be replaced by a type variable

```
void foo( List<List<?>> arg )
```

is very different from

```
<T> 
void foo( List<List<T>> arg)
```

This is because wildcard capture conversion is only applied to 1st level wildcards. Let's talk about these.

Due to extensive capture conversion, in most places, compiler treats wildcards as if they are type variables. Therefore indeed programmer can replace wildcard with type variables in such places, a sort of manual capture conversion.

Since a type variable created by compiler for capture conversion is not accessible to programmer, this has the restricting effect mentioned by @josefx. For example, compiler treats a `List<?>` object as a `List<W>` object; since `W` is internal to compiler, although it has a method `add(W item)`, there's no way for programmer to invoke it, because he has no item of type `W`. However, if programmer "manually" converts the wildcard to a type variable `T`, he can have an item with type `T` and invoke `add(T item)` on it.

Another rather random case where wildcard can't be replaced type variable:

```
class Base
    List<? extends Number> foo()

class Derived extends Base
    List<Integer> foo()
```

Here, foo() is overriden with a covariant return type, since `List<Integer>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Number`. This won't work if the wildcard is replaced with type variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a usage difference for your examples.

```
public <T> List<? extends T> dummy2(List<? extends T> list);
```

returns a list that can contain an unknown subtype of T so you can get objects of type T out of it but can't add to it.

Example T = Number

```
List<? extends Number> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer(1)));
//Valid since the values are guaranteed to be a subtype of Number
Number o = l.get(0);
//Invalid since we don't know that the valuetype of the list is Integer
l.add(new Integer(1));
```

So the wildcard can be used to make some operations invalid, this can be used by an API to restrict an interface.

Example:

```
//Use to remove unliked numbers, thanks to the wildcard 
//it is impossible to add a Number
@Override public void removeNumberCallback(List<? extends Number> list){
    list.remove(13);
}
```